# How to translate mouse point of Tab to Point of JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

Sorry, but I am afraid!

I have mouse listener attached to my custom tab component. 
When I click on this tab I want to translate mouse Point to coordinates of parent JTabbedPane.

How to do this in swing?

Thanks friends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeares to be very easy to do.

Class `javax.swing.SwingUtilities` has a set of methods that convert Point and Rectangle from coordinate system of one component to another component.

It is also possible to convert MouseEvent.